# OleDB Access to Access mdb with Query less rows

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, oledb

my source is the following:

```
    Dim Connection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=datenbank.mdb")
    Connection.open()
    Dim queryString As String
    Dim DBreader As OleDbDataReader
    queryString = "SELECT * FROM datenbank"
    Dim command As New OleDbCommand(queryString, Connection)
 DBreader = command.ExecuteReader()
    Try
        While (DBreader.Read())
            MsgBox(DBreader("0").ToString() & ", " & DBreader("1").ToString() & ", " & DBreader("2").ToString() & ", " & DBreader("3").ToString() & ", " & DBreader("4").ToString())
        End While
        DBreader.Close()

        Connection.close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

I get the right count of Columns but no records back of my query.

What is here wrong?

Comment: `I get the right count of Columns but no records back of my query.`  What does that mean?  You are only put the records into a MessageBox.  You aren't returning anything or doing anything else with the information.  Side note: always put your disposable database objects into Using-End Using blocks.  Your connection string looks flaky because you don't include the path.

Comment: What is the goal with the data you're querying?

Comment: My Question is, why not any rows are returned.

Comment: The goal is to get first a running bare bone before the start of the rest developing work.

Comment: Right, but no records putted into an MessageBox are displayed.

Comment: Does anyone know, how to get this source above runnable?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code. It works perfectly when I try it. The only change I had to make was to fully specify the path to datenbank.mdb. In my case e:\datenbank.mdb. You should not call columns 0...4 like that as it confuses ordinal positions of columns and column names. Also please consider using Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 instead of the old Jet driver as it has been deprecated for about 15 years.